# Distributing free ios apps privately to multiple customers (b2b?)

Tags: b2b

I have been researching a lot about this issue, but I only get more and more confused...

Basically, what I need to do is to distribute a free ios app, but I don't want it to be available to everyone, but just to some of my customers (5 or 6 companies). I have been looking into the B2B option, but I have some questions:

- The purchasing company must enroll in the Volume Purchase Program... will this be free for them?
- Can I distribute the same app to more than one company?
- How exactly can I perfom the distribution? Can I just publish my .ipa through one of my servers? Or do I need to go with a MDM? I have read that it is actually the purchasing company who has to get and manage the MDM?
- According to Apple : "Even though custom B2B apps can be free, you must have a Paid Applications contract for your app to be visible on the Custom B2B App Store."... what does that mean?
- Maybe there is another better option for me than the B2B program?

Sorry for asking so many questions, and many thanks in advance!!

María.

Answer (score 7):

When distributing an iOS app b2b:

- any buyer must be enrolled in the Volume Purchase Program (this is free).
- you must specifically allow all buyers (there can be more than one) to purchase by specifying their Apple ID in iTunes connect.
- the buyer pays whatever price you specify for the app on a per install basis and Apple takes their 30% cut.  This can specify a price of zero.
- distribution is entirely Apple-hosted but the app is not visible in the public app store.
- The Paid Applications Contract is an agreement between you and Apple that you must enter into before using B2B distribution.  Steps to make the agreement are here - http://www.pressmatrix.de/product-blog/apple-developer-itunes-connect-guide/

Note that b2b apps MUST go through Apple review process.

The only other option I see is to require your clients to enroll in the iOS Developer Enterprise program (cost of $300 per year) and then allow you to sign the app with their certificates for distribution to their employees using "over the air" installation, config utils, or an MDM.

Comment: astletron is correct, your scenario is the use-case that B2B is designed for.  To be more explicit on distribution, the companies you allow to see and purchase your B2B app will distribute your app by using VPP and can couple VPP with their own MDM solution in place to distribute the apps easily to the devices they manage.  You, as the developer, do not need MDM and do not need to do anything to distribute your app once you've submitted it up to Apple and properly whitelisted the companies. https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

Answer (score -1):

It sounds as though you might want the [iOS Developer Enterprise program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/).

This enables you to distribute apps ad hoc, however you might want to check whether that means to one organisation or to multiple as I'm unsure.

[Comparison of the iOS developer programs](https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/)

Comment: The iOS Developer Enterprise program is only for companies building apps that will be used by employees of that company.  The license agreements forbids using an enterprise certificate to sign an app that will be used by employees of another (e.g. a client) company.